# Advice on buying a 4k Tv

Tags: television

Im looking into buying a new 50 inch 4K HDR Tv for gaming and general television functions.

I really like the [Panasonic DX802b](https://www.panasonic.com/uk/consumer/televisions/4KTV/tx-50dx802b.html) but my main concern (although it is HDR ready) is that it will soon be overlooked my newer OLED models that are coming down in price while this tv is still using LED technology.

The 802b is getting great [reviews](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/panasonic/1405341/panasonic-tx-50dx802b-review-a-superb-4k-hdr-tv) online and for £800 here in the UK it seems like a bargain.

With a budget of about £1000 (roughly about $1340) will this be a good investment for the next 4-5 years?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Besides res, size, and HDR support, are there any other concerns you have?

Comment: @JMY1000 Thanks for your comment.  I guess general future proofing i.e. hdr10 support and likelihood of oled tv's coming down in price.